# How to cover all spectrum in wavelet when it which is behalved?

Tags: wavelet

As I know , wavelet decomposition behave with halve.
I mean that a way like this HH HL LH LL.

But I wonder, how to corver the all spectrum when it was halved?
I think if it want to all cover spectrum then it might be needed infinity halve.

How can cover all the spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is covered - its just the signal that is the residual part of what you didn't filter yet.

Comment: Would you please let me know more? Does it just remain residual ? I don't understand. Because that way is not cover aren't you?

Comment: The discrete wavelet generates "filter banks". After the first iteration, you are left with two signals - a signal that only contains frequencies from sampling rate/2 to sampling rate/4 Hz (this is the high frequency bank that you just filtered out) and another signal that only contains frequencies from sampling frequency/4 to zero Hz. If you have enough samples left in the low frequency bank, you can repeat the filtration process again - if you repeat again you will now be left with 3 signals.

Comment: However, it should be noted that this is the case for discrete wavelet filtration - a process that uses "continuous" transform methods may achieve better frequency resolution within the filter banks.

Comment: Thanks. But as you can said, that way need a cock. What if I havd enough decomposition then should I have to ignore or throw out the rest part?

Comment: What do you mean by "need a cock"?